# ¿Por que aparece este error en mi codigo? X, Y = map(int, input().split()) ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)

Tags: python

Realizando un ejercicio basico, me sale este error, por lo que entiendo, el programa solo me recibe 1 valor y debe recibir 2

MI CODIGO

```py
X, Y = map(int, input().split())
while X != 0 and Y != 0:
    X, Y = map(int, input().split())
    if X > 0 and X < 100 and Y > 0 and Y < 100 :
        print("CUADRANTE I")
    elif X > -100 and X < 0 and Y > 0 and Y < 100 :
        print("CUADRANTE II")
    elif X > -100 and X < 0 and Y > -100 and Y < 0 :
        print("CUADRANTE III")
    elif X > 0 and X < 100 and Y > -100 and Y < 0 :
        print("CUADRANTE IV")
```

Comment: Que mensaje escribes en el input que te da error?

Comment: Split si no le pasas ningun argumento separa la palabra segun espacios y saltos de linea. Tiene que haber exactamemte dos "palabras" que solo tengan numeros para que no suceda error.

Comment: Estoy realizando el ejercicio para un juez online, por lo tanto no requiere insertar un mensaje en el input, de lo contrario seria un error mas para el juez

Comment: Si no insertas nada en el input claramente dará error

Comment: Ya intente ingresando letras en el input pero me sale lo mismo, los valores que pongo de prueba son: 1 y 2

Comment: Pones "1 2" en el input? o 1 en un input y 2 en otro?

Comment: Noooo, al momento de ingresar los valores pero apenas los ingreso, me sale ese error

Comment: y acabo de intentar otra vez pero me sale esto: EOF when reading a line

Comment: Probé diversos numeros separados con un espacio y me funciona perfecto. Que esperas que ingrese el usuario? Lo del eof no tengo idea de por que sea...

Comment: También lo he probado y funciona. Sería mejor si colocas la forma en que lo estas probando

Comment: Si, era eso ya lo solucione. El problema que tenia era por que separaba la entrada con una coma ‍♂️

Comment: No hay problema, todos nos equivocamos c:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para un correcto funcionamiento, en la entrada estandar, los valores deben estar separados por un espacio, ej: `1 2`, esto se debe a que el parámetro `sep` del método `split()` tiene un espacio como valor por defecto, para alterar este comportamiento, poner una coma por ejemplo, debemos sobreescribir dicho valor `split(sep=',')` de esta forma tenemos un nuevo separador ej: `1,2`.

Por otra parte, la linea `X, Y = map(int, input().split())` dentro del ciclo debería estar colocada al final del mismo, porque estando en la primera linea sería necesario ingresar 2 veces los valores en la primera iteración, ya que se piden antes de entrar al ciclo y una vez dentro. Con lo anterior también nos aseguramos que los valores sean validados por la condición del `while` antes de entrar en el bloque `if-elif-else`.

Como punto adicional, se podría agregar un `else` para mostrar un mensaje en caso que los valores entrados de `X` y `Y` no estén en el rango de 0 a 99.

```py
    X, Y = map(int, input().split())
    while X != 0 and Y != 0:
        if 0 < X < 100 and 0 < Y < 100:
            print("CUADRANTE I")
        elif -100 < X < 0 and 0 < Y < 100:
            print("CUADRANTE II")
        elif -100 < X < 0 and -100 < Y < 0:
            print("CUADRANTE III")
        elif 0 < X < 100 and -100 < Y < 0:
            print("CUADRANTE IV")
        else:
            print('VALORES FUERA DE RANGO 1-99')
        X, Y = map(int, input().split())
```